# TableView in a tableView chrashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `static UItableView`. In one of the `cells`, I have a `dynamic prototype UITableView`. Here is the code I implemented:

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.tagsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hey", @"what", @"ola", @"dada", @"hoster", @"umi", nil];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.tableView == tableView ? 2 : 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.tableView == tableView)
        return (section == 0) ? 3 : 2;
    else
        return [self.tagsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (self.tableView == tableView) {
        cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.textLabel setText:self.tagsArray [indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

When I run the app, everything works fine. But when I start scrolling on the inner `tableView` (the dynamic prototype one), then I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001012a7c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000100f40bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010119e17e -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 190
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000101e12132 -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:] + 106
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001019dc1f9 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 1711
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010195a68e +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001019dbb3b -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 312
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001019e3a41 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 533
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001019c2248 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2853
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001019d88a9 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 210
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000101962a2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100934ec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001009296d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100929546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100895886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100896a3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001008970eb _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001011daca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001011dac00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001011d0a33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001011d0366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010510da3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001018e2900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  myApp                               0x00000001004cf51f main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102cfe145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't know what the above error means, but I think that it's not creating new `cells` for some reason, and because of that, it has a conflict with the number of `cells` to display, so it crashes with the above error.

Why isn't the inner `tableView` creating new `cells`, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Nesting table views can get weird. It looks like UITableViewDataSource tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: is doing the out of bounds access, and that method is probably implemented in the superclass. I wonder if refactoring so that the different table views have different delegate implementations would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that you tried to access an element that doesn't exist.

Your data array only has 2 elements, but you are hardcoding the amount of cells you want to create (3) so when it looks for the 3rd element to create the cell it crashes because is not existent.

Comment: Thanks for answering!! My array has 5 objects. It's the `self.tagsArray`